# DbContext instance not changing with dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, backgroundworker, dbcontext

In my application, I have an API and a worker, that both need to use my database. I have a repository layer, that is accessed by both of these.
I use DI in my application, and I inject my dbContext in my repositories.

While I expect my repositories to use a new dbContext on every request, the instance seems to always be the same.

Since I have a background worker, which is a singleton, I was not able to use the default scoped lifetime of my dbContext. Therefore I have added my dbContext as transient in both my worker and my API. I have added an instanceId to my dbContext, which is set in my constructor.

Constructor of dbcontext:

```
 public CatAPIDbContext()
    {
        InstanceId = Guid.NewGuid();
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
```

Worker configureservices:

```
  public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddDbContext<CatAPIDbContext>(ServiceLifetime.Transient);
            services.AddTransient(typeof(IFeedingProfileRepository), typeof(FeedingProfileRepository));
            services.AddTransient(typeof(IFeedingTimesRepository), typeof(FeedingTimesRepository));
            services.AddTransient(typeof(IFeedHistoryRepository), typeof(FeedHistoryRepository));
            services.AddTransient(typeof(IMotorController), typeof(MotorController));
            services.AddTransient(typeof(IFoodDispenser), typeof(FoodDispenser));
            services.AddTransient(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
            services.AddTransient(typeof(IFeedingTimeChecker), typeof(FeedingTimeChecker));
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        });
```

API ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvcCore().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
    services.AddDbContext<CatAPIDbContext>();
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IFeedingProfileRepository), typeof(FeedingProfileRepository));
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IFeedingTimesRepository), typeof(FeedingTimesRepository));
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IFeedHistoryRepository), typeof(FeedHistoryRepository));
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IMotorController), typeof(MotorController));
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IFoodDispenser), typeof(FoodDispenser));
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
}
```

GenericRepo example:

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
public CatAPIDbContext _dbContext { get; set; }
public GenericRepository(CatAPIDbContext dbContext)
{
    _dbContext = dbContext;
}

public T GetById(object id)
{
    return _dbContext.Set<T>().Find(id);
}
}
```

Repo that I use and does not get latest state example:

```
 public class FeedingProfileRepository : 
GenericRepository<FeedingProfile>, IFeedingProfileRepository
{
    public FeedingProfileRepository(CatAPIDbContext dbContext) : 
base(dbContext)
    {
    }

    public FeedingProfile GetCurrentFeedingProfile()
    {
        var profile = _dbContext.FeedingProfiles
            .Include(x => x.TimesToFeedOn)
            .Where(x => x.CurrentlyActive == true).FirstOrDefault();


        if (profile == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (profile.TimesToFeedOn != null)
        {
            profile.TimesToFeedOn = profile.TimesToFeedOn.OrderByDescending(x => x.Time).ToList();
        }
        return profile;

    }
}
```

When thw orker calls FeedingProfileRepository.GetCurrentFeedingProfile() I check the instanceId of the dbContext, and it is always the same during the entire lifetime of my application. As a result, the data I retrieve from the dbContext is outdated, and does not match the current state of the database, since the dbContext never gets disposed. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your code you've made dbContext Transient and it means that it is created a new instance  every time they are injected or requested:

```
 services.AddDbContext<CatAPIDbContext>(ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

if you want to have a single instance for all of the requests, make it singleton  try to change your code like below:

```
services.AddDbContext<CatAPIDbContext>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
```

But if you want to have a single instance for every request to application try to use scoped lifetime:

```
 services.AddDbContext<CatAPIDbContext>(ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, the dbContext is supposed to be very short lived, so I want to refrain from using a singleton scope. The problem however is that I would like to use my dbContext as a scoped lifetime, but I can't since I am using it in my worker, which is a singleton. I can't add a scoped dbContext to my singleton worker. On top of that, I would not expect the transient lifetime, which is supposed to be the most short lived, refreshing on every inject/request to never change, and always be the same throughout the entire lifetime of my application.

Comment: You cannot  Consume Scoped Service From Singleton, try to avoid this situation, for more information read this: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/03/20/cannot-consume-scoped-service-from-singleton-a-lesson-in-asp-net-core-di-scopes/

Comment: I had indeed read that article, while it explains my problem, it does not seem to provide a solution for the 'singleton transient trap'. Since I have no choice but for my worker to be a singleton, and I cannot add my dbContext as Scoped, I feel like I have no choice but to add it as transient, which leads me again to the singleton transient trap. I have tried keeping my own scope in my worker, which worked, but it decreased testability significantly, so I am still out looking for a better solution.